# Cannot debug or hit breakpoints in Javascript with VSCode

Tags: javascript, windows, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am following this tutorial video to debug Javascript in Windows 10 with VSCode and Edge Browser,
https://youtu.be/68wO-sl5vXg?t=148
I get to the point of creating a launch.json configuration at 2:29.
However, when I click "Run And Debug", it doesn't automatically create the Launch.json file. I need to click on "Create a launch.json File" below that to create it.

This would be fine, except the launch.json file that is created completely differs from what is in the video, it doesn't show the URL or WebRoot, I pasted what it looks like below.
So I went ahead and I added the URL and webroot fields.

Still, when I click on on the Debug button "Open index.html" nothing happens, none of my breakpoints are hit.
What am I missing here, how can I make these breakpoints work?

Thanks,

```
 {
 // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
 // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
 // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
        {
 "type": "msedge",
 "request": "launch",
 "name": "Open index.html",
 "file": "c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\smtexplorer\\index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```